# Jquery Content Slider Plugin that is able to change slide order dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am looking for a jquery content slider plugin that is able to have its slide order changed dynamically after the page load. This is a feature that I would like the user to be able to control in the end.

Maybe a less intensive requirement would be a content slider that is able to have its settings changed dynamically after the page load. That will at least give me something to work with.

I looked through the StackExchange sites, and could not find a better site to ask this question on. I've spent a couple hours researching different sliders and looking for similar questions to mine, but could not find any.

What I mean by content slider is not the Jquery-UI slider, but something similar to this: http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-onebyone-slider-plugin/684613

Comment: "slider" what do you mean ? Slideshow ?

Comment: @Grsmto A slideshow of a sort. The term that a lot of web developers use is content slider. I updated my post with a link to an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting for an answer, and not receiving one, I decided to push out my own solution as there does not actually seem to be one in existence.

The following solution does work, but it's a bit messy still and needs touching up. All you have to do is move the number icons in the order you want them, and the sliding images reflect that order. This plugin will work with slides that aren't just images as well, you can put HTML into them.

Here's a link to the zip file with all the relevant files. I ended up using Basic Jquery Slider and Jquery-UI Sortable together to achieve what I needed done.

http://www.speedyshare.com/DkzkQ/Basic-Slider.zip   (Click the link at the top, not the big button at the bottom).

Comment: Can you share a demo mate?